# Should a question on what happens in 4-4 ruling in SCOTUS be asked on Politics or Law SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should a question on what happens in/after 4-4 ruling in SCOTUS (Supreme Court of the United States) be asked on Politics or Law SE?

Comment: @Sally - legal implications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd consider that question to be on topic.

I'd say that it is a question about governments and how they work.  It's a matter of the State, which is what "Politics" means.

I expect it to be on topic for Law.SE, but there is no rule that says that you can't ask questions that would be on topic at Law.SE